# How to move the Camera in Unity Panorama Street view?

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine, skybox

## ↪️ I want to embed a street view in app so I created a new Project

---

[image]

---

## ↪️ Added Street View To Skybox from the asset store

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

## ↪️ Imorted a street view from google maps to a Skybox

---

[image]

[image]

---

## ↪️ Drag and droped the sky box in the scene

---

[image]

---

## ↪️ how I do move the camera in response to the touch and mouse moment like a panorama in this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-custom-simple)

---

## ↪️

1.[Unit 3d documentation](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/editor/interface-overview?playlist=17090)

2.[Unity Touch Swipe Camera Rotation - Touch FPS Controller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrrfAVNDudc)

3.[Street View Convert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLsdhn3_0Z8)

4.[Street view converter unity 3D panorama](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnR62x3wkCg)

5.[Unity3D Tutorial: How to make Skybox 360 single texture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F93wzC-JzDc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do the following:

- Create an empty GameObject called "RotorY" which will be responsible for y rotation of your camera (looking around).
- Create an empty GameObject "RotorX" as a child of "RotorY". This one will control x rotation (looking up and down)
- Make camera a child of RotorX. (also make sure RotorX and Camera have (0,0,0) position in local space)
- Add [this script](https://justpaste.it/12hsu) to any gameObject and assign rotorY and rotorX to the slots (while experimenting I ended up writing this script, lol)

EDIT January, 2017: added 2 lines in the code to make it work with unity 5.5

Comment: finally working thanks , but when i click (one click) the camera move down very fast  ?! @nika-kasradze

Comment: @Nika Kasradze, Thank you. Works like a charm. No muss, no fuss.